# Como carregar 2 ajax na mesma pagina?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Olá. Eu gostaria de fazer com que essa consulta ajax retornasse o valor para ser colocado em seguida e alimente a o gráfico. Estou rodando, mas o valor não esta sendo carregado, o gráfico aparece vazio. Algum problema em carregar dois ajax ao mesmo tempo?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//controller/entrega.js"></script>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
        <style type="text/css">


        </style>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var testegraf;
            var endereco = 'http://pipageo.ngrok.io/regre';

            $.ajax({
                url: endereco,
                complete: function(res) {
                    var meuJSON = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
                    testegraf = (meuJSON);
                }
            });


            $(function() {

                // Give the points a 3D feel by adding a radial gradient
                Highcharts.getOptions().colors = $.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
                    return {
                        radialGradient: {
                            cx: 0.4,
                            cy: 0.3,
                            r: 0.5
                        },
                        stops: [
                            [0, color],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.2).get('rgb')]
                        ]
                    };
                });

                var nome = testegraf;

                // Set up the chart
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        margin: 100,
                        type: 'scatter',
                        options3d: {
                            enabled: true,
                            alpha: 10,
                            beta: 30,
                            depth: 250,
                            viewDistance: 5,
                            fitToPlot: false,
                            frame: {
                                bottom: {
                                    size: 1,
                                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.02)'
                                },
                                back: {
                                    size: 1,
                                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.04)'
                                },
                                side: {
                                    size: 1,
                                    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.06)'
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Dispersão Cisternas'
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: 'X - Regressão | Y - Dias | X - Capacidade',
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        scatter: {
                            width: 50,
                            height: 50,
                            depth: 50
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 50,
                        title: null
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 20,
                        gridLineWidth: 1
                    },
                    zAxis: {
                        min: 0,
                        max: 20,
                        showFirstLabel: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Regressão',
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        data: (testegraf)
                    }]
                });


                // Add mouse events for rotation
                $(chart.container).bind('mousedown.hc touchstart.hc', function(eStart) {
                    eStart = chart.pointer.normalize(eStart);

                    var posX = eStart.pageX,
                        posY = eStart.pageY,
                        alpha = chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha,
                        beta = chart.options.chart.options3d.beta,
                        newAlpha,
                        newBeta,
                        sensitivity = 5; // lower is more sensitive

                    $(document).bind({
                        'mousemove.hc touchdrag.hc': function(e) {
                            // Run beta
                            newBeta = beta + (posX - e.pageX) / sensitivity;
                            chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = newBeta;

                            // Run alpha
                            newAlpha = alpha + (e.pageY - posY) / sensitivity;
                            chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha = newAlpha;

                            chart.redraw(false);
                        },
                        'mouseup touchend': function() {
                            $(document).unbind('.hc');
                        }
                    });
                });

            });

        </script>


    </head>

    <body>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Sergio Poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Não há problema em ter 2 ou mais ajax por página.  Nesta página só vejo um. Qual é a funcionalidade que falta (ou seja que o outro ajax deveria fazer)? Estás a carregar o jQuery 2 vezes... a versão `1.4` e `1.9` há alguma razão?

Comment: Eu acho que sei o que se passa, deve chamar a função que monta o gráfico no `success` do ajax, pois `testegraf` não vai ter o valor esperado no carregamento da página, mas sim só depois da chamada de ajax ser bem sucedida, uma referência: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success. Esta linha: `data: (testegraf)` só fará sentido depois de ter os valores esperados em `testegraf`

Comment: Teria que ter algo assim?  var testegraf = function testAjax() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: endereco,  
                    success:function(data) {

                    }
                });
                return data; 
            }

Comment: Nop, podes chamar uma função que crie o gráfico e passas os dados como argumento: `monta_graph(testegraf);`

Comment: Tentei fazer o que me indicou @Miguel, mas não tive sucesso. Você não poderia realizar a modificação para mim?? Por favor!

Comment: Não garanto que vá resultar mas seria algo assim: https://jsfiddle.net/hg2cumy5/1/. Também não percebo o porque tem isto `var nome = testegraf;` visto que no código que colocou não usa a var `nome`

Comment: Não pegou não. Se eu conseguisse fazer a variavel testegraf receber o resultado de pipageo.../regre, meu problema estaria resolvido. Já tentei usar o location,assign mas ele renderiza a pagina toda HTML, queria apenas os valores. Tem como usar o location.assign e antes dele renderizar capturar os valores da tag que os contem e assim montar o testegraf?